# How to pass text from one activity to another activty (android studio)

Tags: java, xml, android-layout

Hi I'm kind of new to Java and Android Studio and I am trying to dynamically display a battery percentage and local time. I am basically trying to create a status bar for a watch. I have a main activity, second activity and a third activity. I've managed to have the battery and time change on the main activity, but when I go to my second and third activity it shows my filler values. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

To start another Activity:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(contest, TargetClass.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

To add parameters for TargetActivity:

```
 i.putExtra("myparametername","myparametervalue");
```

complete sample:

```
Intent i = new Intent(contest, TargetClass.class);
i.putExtra("myparametername","myparametervalue")
startActivity(i)
```

Android studio Will suggest you what type of parameter to pass.
My advice Is to use a constant for parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

//Create Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("parameter1", value1);
intent.putExtra("parameter2", value2);
intent.putExtra("parameterN", valueN);

startActivity(intent);
```

Get the data

```
//Remember to get the data of the same type that you defined in your putExtra()
value1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("parameter1");
value2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("parameter2");
valueN = getIntent().getStringExtra("parameterN");
```

You can review [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application?rq=1)